# Prove the following inequality without using differentiation

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers that satisfy $0\le a,b,c\le 1$. Show that

$$\frac a{b+c+1} + \frac b{a+c+1}  + \frac c{a+b+1} + (1-a)(1-b)(1-c) \le 1.$$

I don't know where to start. Multiplying everything by the denominators creates extreme mess.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: @AlexR I added +3 in the LHS but that didn't work, i think this is more complicated than just simplifying the functions in LHS...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WLOG: $a\le b\le c$, then
\begin{align*}&\dfrac{a}{b+c+1}+\dfrac{b}{c+a+1}+\dfrac{c}{a+b+1}+(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)\\
&\le\dfrac{a}{a+b+1}+\dfrac{b}{a+b+1}+\dfrac{c}{a+b+1}+(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)\\
&=\dfrac{a+b+c}{a+b+1}+\dfrac{(a+b+1)(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}{a+b+1}\\
&\le\dfrac{a+b+c}{a+b+1}+\dfrac{(1+a)(1+b)(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}{a+b+1}\\
&=\dfrac{a+b+c}{a+b+1}+\dfrac{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)(1-c)}{a+b+1}\\
&\le\dfrac{a+b+c}{a+b+1}+\dfrac{(1-c)}{a+b+1}\\
&=1
\end{align*}

Comment: you are a true mathematician Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(a, b, c)$ denote the left hand side of the inequality. Since $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}f=\frac{2b}{(a+c+1)^3}+\frac{2c}{(a+b+1)^3}\ge0$$we have that $f$ is convex in each of the three variables; hence,
the maximum must occur where $a, b, c \in \{0, 1\}$. Since $f$ is $1$ at each of these $8$ points,
the inequality follows.

Comment: without using differentiation;;

Comment: i've solved it with using it that's an easy one. but just elementary algebra, it is quite difficult